# XML Import with "alternate" form or xml formatting

Tags: sql, xml, formatting

I have successfully imported an XML file parsing elements info table attributes using this xml data formating:

```
<PN>
    <guid>aaaa</guid>
    <dataInput>0</dataInput>
    <deleted>false</deleted>
    <customField1></customField1>
    <customField2></customField2>
    <customField3></customField3>
    <description></description>
    <name>name1></name>
    <ccid>CC007814</ccid>
    <productIds>bbbb</productIds>
</PN>
```

but it errors whwen I input an XML in this format:

```
<PN guid="aaaa" 
    deleted="false" 
    customField1="" 
    customField2="" 
    customField3="" 
    description="" 
    modified="2010-10-20T00:00:00.001" 
    created="2010-05-20T18:07:10.416" 
    name="name1" 
    ccid="CC006035" 
    productIds="bbbb"/>
```

Is this later form usable? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's usable, but you're looking at the difference between using tags (your first example) and attributes (your second example).  Your processing is slightly different.